# pass function-pointer to non-static member-function

Tags: c++, pointers, curl

I am coding a program that will automatically trade at various bitcoin exchanges. Since every exchange has it's on API, i made a wrapper class for every API that represents the exchange:

```
class BITSTAMP : public EXCHANGE {
    public:
       int callbackFunction(int parameter)
       {
       //code
       }
}
```

the callback function is supposed to handle the JSON-string that the server sends as reply.

i am using the curl library to communicate with the server and i need to pass curl a function-pointer to my callback-function like this:

```
curl_easy_setopt(CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, functionPointer);
```

(functionPointer being a normal static function that is implicitly converted to a pointer)

But since BITSTAMP::callbackFunction() is a non-static member (and i can not make it static), i don't know how to pass a pointer to curl :( 
My compiler suggests to use &BITSTAMP::callbackFunction but obviously it can not be called without an instance -> segfault

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function that you supply to CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION needs to match this prototype:

```
size_t function(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata);
```

The parameter "userdata" is anything you specify with [CURLOPT_WRITEDATA](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTWRITEDATA), so you can make the instance the "userdata" parameter, in which case the body of your function can do:

```
 BITSTAMP* instance = static_cast<BITSTAMP*>(userdata);
 int parameter = // ...
 instance->callbackFunction(parameter);
```

.. in order to invoke the member function. (While it is true that C++ supports pointers to member functions, a member function pointer wouldn't help you here, since you still need an instance in order to dereference it).

Comment: thx for your input, it works like a charm :D But suppose you'd use an API which doesn't have that kind of a userdata-parameter, so you'd be forced to pass a pointer to non-static member-function, how would you do that? You never know what you will encounter in your live, so i'll better learn it right away.